# CCSprite doesn't display on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I have a an app using cocos2D for a mini-game.
When I push a button, I launch a cocos2D scene with the game.

I try to load just a image in background (bg.png) in my cocos2D scene. I'm using sprites.

It works on iPhone 5 and iPhone 4S (iOS 6), but it doesn't work on the iPhone 4.
On the iPhone 4 I have a black screen. I don't understand why.

sprites-hd.png does 3762 × 1252, 1,4 Mo. Is it too big for the iPhone 4 ?

In my GameViewController_iPhone.m :

```
-(IBAction) playGame {

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[ISAMAppDelegate_iPhone sharedISAMAppDelegate].window bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setView:glView];

    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        MyLog(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];    
    [self.view addSubview:glView];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[Game sceneWithGameViewController:self]];
}
```

In my Game.m :

```
+ (CCScene *)sceneWithGameViewController:(GameViewController_iPhone*) gvc
{
    CCScene *game = [CCScene node];

    Game *layer = [[Game alloc] initWithGameViewController:gvc];
    [game addChild:layer];

    return game;
}


- (id) initWithGameViewController:(GameViewController_iPhone*) gvc {

    if(![super init]) return nil;

    if((self = [super init])) {

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprites.plist"];

        CCSpriteBatchNode* batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprites.png" capacity:50];

        [self addChild:batchNode];

        CCSprite *someSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bg.png"];
        [batchNode addChild:someSprite];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load textures larger than 2048x2048 in iPhone 4, so you may split your current sprite atlas.

Comment: cocos has nothing to do with that, its a device limitation.